# ROS Debugging VSCode Python

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I have read/tried various solutions in an attempt to debug ROS in VS Code without any luck. Can I please get some help in solving this mystery?

My workspace runs fine from when I run from an Ubuntu terminal prompt and from an IDE terminal prompt.
source devel/setup.bash
rosrun location tagsub.py

My env:
Ubuntu 16.04
VS Code IDE
ROS extension installed

My ROS package:
Name: location
Simple pub/sub with a custom message

From an Ubuntu terminal prompt I go to my workspace root, and start code.
In VS Code terminal (which is on my workspace root), run catkin build then roscore. In the lower left corner of IDE, ROS Master now has a check mark.

I then created a launch configuration by:

1. clicking on the debug icon on the left most part of the IDE
2. clicking on the gear icon on the upper left section of the IDE, this opens a new launch.json file
3. click on the the button Add Configuration...(in the lower right of the window). This pulls up a window of choices
4. choose {} ROS : rosrun
5. Here is my launch entry:

   ```
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "ros",
      "command": "rosrun",
      "name": "rosrun",
      "package": "location",
      "target": "tagsub.py",
      "debugSettings": "debugSettings"
    }
   ```
6. Click on my source file tagsub.py file tag in the editer window
7. Press F5

The debug process starts and get this error:
Exception has occurred: str

```
'No module named rospy'
  File "/home/zzfl0b/location/src/location/scripts/tagsub.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
```

In IDE terminal pip list | grep ros returns:

```
gazebo-ros                    2.5.17
rosbag                        1.12.13
rosboost-cfg                  1.14.3
rosclean                      1.14.3
roscreate                     1.14.3
rosgraph                      1.12.13
roslaunch                     1.12.13
roslib                        1.14.3
roslint                       0.11.0
roslz4                        1.12.13
rosmake                       1.14.3
rosmaster                     1.12.13
rosmsg                        1.12.13
rosnode                       1.12.13
rosparam                      1.12.13
rospy                         1.12.13
rosservice                    1.12.13
rostest                       1.12.13
rostopic                      1.12.13
rosunit                       1.14.3
roswtf                        1.12.13
smach-ros                     2.0.1
tf2-ros                       0.5.17
```

Also from an IDE terminal prompt,

```
$ env | grep ros:
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/jeff/location/src/roscpp:/home/jeff/location/src/rospy:/home/jeff/location/src/std_msgs:/home/jeff/location/src/location:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jeff/location/devel/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/jeff/bin:/home/jeff/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PYTHONPATH=/home/jeff/location/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/jeff/location/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/jeff/location/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301015/ros-debugging-vscode-python/) by [JeffBlumenthal](https://answers.ros.org/users/33936/jeffblumenthal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-08-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-08-21**:
you need to setup your environment for debugging and source that path, then run your package and link it from VSCode

**Comment by [JeffBlumenthal](https://answers.ros.org/users/33936/jeffblumenthal/) on 2018-08-21**:
@Choco93, can you please be more specific on how to do this? I have also tried running source devel/setup.bash from a launch pretask and it still is not working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There might be other ways but this is one I know:

1. Go into your workspace and show hidden folders (ctrl+h)
2. There is folder called .catkin_tools, and a sub folder called profiles. Go into profiles and make a copy of your default profile. Call it debug (or anything you like). Go into debug and change build.yaml and config.yaml to not to have build and devel but to have debug_devel and build_devel (again you can name them anything).`build_space: build_debug & devel_space: devel_debug`.
3. Then build your package in debug mode add a flag when building `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug`.
4. When it's built, source devel_debug/setup.bash and run your node.
5. Then go into VSCode and debug mode (ctrl+shift+D), you will see green play button on top right press that, it will probably prompt to launch a json, open it and configure it for your python node [see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).
6. Once configured you can chose that configuration and press play button it will pop-up a list of available process to link against, select your node from it, it will ask for password and then you can debug.

It seems lengthy but most of it is just one time configuration thing, once that is done you can change node name and path in configuration to work with any other python node. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeffBlumenthal](https://answers.ros.org/users/33936/jeffblumenthal/) on 2018-08-23**:
Thank you for your response/help.

So step 4 runs the node and step 6 attaches to it? In the launch.json I have program set to ${workspaceFolder}/src/location/scripts/locationByName_service.py

It starts ok, then errors out on import rospy with module not found error.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-08-24**:
Welcome, 4 and 6 work exactly as you mentioned. And I don't know where this error is coming from, don't remember encountering this. Maybe you can ask a new question about it in more details and close this one.